# Made partial to landscaper last spring?

Tags: statute-of-limitations, missouri

I live in Missouri.
I met with a landscaper last spring, he gave me a price of $3700 to do some work about 9 months ago.  The company didn't have time to do this work or couldn't fit it in or whatever but now, 9 months later.. I'm asking for my (partial payment $2000) back and he's saying they will mail it but I get this funny feeling that they wont. The reason is that I see a lot of online reviews where others are saying they got ripped off by this company.  So my question is, how long do I have?  Like is there some sort of time-span where a 'limitation' kicks in? (I don't know the legal terms).  What can I do if this company doesn't pay me back and keeps making excuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 years from when you paid.

http://www.moga.mo.gov/mostatutes/stathtml/40000207251.html

Comment: The OP should note that that's four years to commencement of a lawsuit, not four years until he/she talks to an attorney or writes a demand letter.